# Is existence restricted by rendering?

Tags: consciousness, existence, existentialism

Is existence restricted by the rendering of the being?
For example, as I am rendered as a physical being in the form of my body, is the plane of my existence limited to the physical world?

I would like to hear some thoughts on this.

Comment: Too vague a question. How "rendering" occurs? Any way, "physical" cannot preceed existence. Primeval "body" coincides with my here facticity in the world. Empirical body is a secondary psychical ("physical") object.

Comment: Your physical being could have a dual aspect. It could be 'thinking matter', matter that has consciousness. As conscious, who knows what planes of existence it might open up ? Some religious hold that through consciousness we have contact with the supernatural. I am merely sketching a conceptual possibility.

Comment: 'Preceed' or perhaps 'precede' (Latin. praecedere) ?

Comment: @Geoffrey, thank you for the grammar check. (English isn't my everyday usage.)

Comment: @ttnphns. I felt a bit guilty for taking up such a minor point. I agreed with your post, which is the best so far. All the best : GT

Comment: @Geoffrey, everything was all right. And your posts are excellent.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please define “rendering of the being” and “plane”.